# Change Auto increment value with sequelize.js in mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there any way to change the autoincrement value to a custom value in sequelize.js?

Comment: There is. Remove auto_increment and do your own logic. It's a bad idea to tamper with auto_increment, so why do you want to do that?

Comment: Well the way I see it, the answer is NO you cannot set a value in an auto incremented column. (That is why it starts with **auto**.) As N.B. has mentioned you would have to alter the column so it is no longer "auto" incremented, but managed by yourself. Which may be a bad idea. Use a new or different column instead.